# Share known WiFi networks between own devices

Tags: wi-fi, share-menu

It happens every now and then that I connect to a WiFi network for the first time on my phone, but not on my tablet. The second time I visit the place I might not have the WiFi access key at hand.
Is there a way to "share" the known network information between own Android devices?

Comment: The easiest way, is using a QR code scanner, to scan the generated code from the wi-fi network. (Note with MIUI the code s generated automatically, otherwise you may need to [generate the QR code manually](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/easily-share-your-wi-fi-password-with-qr-code-your-android-phone-0183483/) before scanning it with the secondary android device

Comment: there is way, but you must create your own app for private use. This one is not what you looking for it is for public sharing only. But maybe you find the right one in suggestions. Let us know https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljapps.wifix.password

Comment: Is there a way to backup and restore through Google account?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to back up and restore though Google (Drive) then perhaps you  may need to look at some third-party applications such as
[WiFi Password Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.zaton.wifipasswordmanager&hl=en) or [Wi-Fi password manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rusdelphi.wifipassword&hl=en) (whichever you prefer as there are more or less similar)

Basically the following features are present:

> - Manage your wifi passwords (add, edit, delete)
> - **Backup your passwords to Google Drive or to local storage**
> - Wifi hotspots list sorted by wifi signal strength
> - Recover wi-fi passwords from system settings (ROOT)
> - Connect to WiFi hotspot directly from the appplication
> - Copy password to clipboard
> - Share wi-fi settings

Pretty straight forward to use simply add the target wi-fi network, then back it up on local or google drive, follow the reverse proceedure to restore:

[image] [image] [image][image]